# Flattening out xml with elements and attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

This is only my second XSLT that I've worked on so still pretty green.

I have xml that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cyber:AOI_INFO xmlns:cyber="http://www.cyberoptics.com/AOI/measure" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.cyberoptics.com/AOI/measure c:/xml/Measure.xsd">
    <UserName>Machine1\User</UserName>
    <SystemId>MACHINE1</SystemId>
    <AOIVersion>4.2.1.24</AOIVersion>
    <InspectionType>Inspection</InspectionType>
    <PositionUnit>Millimeter</PositionUnit>
    <RotationUnit>Degree</RotationUnit>
    <XYOffsetReference>FeatureOrientation</XYOffsetReference>
    <CoplanarityUnit>Angle</CoplanarityUnit>
    <Panel Id="4" Name="Panel" PanelStatus="Failed" StartTime="07/09/2018 
    11:25:53" EndTime="07/09/2018 11:27:40" CycleTime="46" TotalFeatures="10804" 
    TotalComponents="10804" LotCode="New Lot" LotSize="0" Barcode="Failed to Read 
    Barcode" Code="Failed to Read Barcode" NG_Stacker_SlotNumber="">
        <RecipeName>11047-01_OP10_WFR4_R2</RecipeName>
        <RecipeLastUpdateTime></RecipeLastUpdateTime>
        <CAD>D:\Panel.XML</CAD>
        <PanelResult>
            <Attributes>
                <FailedBoards Value="1" />
                <FailedComponents Value="16" />
                <FailedFeatures Value="16" />
            </Attributes>
        </PanelResult>
        <Feature Id="32424" Identifier="BC1" Status="Failed" Value="Failed to Read Barcode" />
        <Board Id="1" Name="Board1" BoardStatus="Failed" TotalFeatures="10804" TotalComponents="10804" Barcode="" Skip="false">
            <BoardResult>
                <Attributes>
                    <FailedComponents Value="16" />
                    <FailedFeatures Value="16" />
                </Attributes>
            </BoardResult>
            <Feature Id="2" Identifier="FID0" Status="Passed" />
            <Feature Id="3" Identifier="FID1" Status="Passed" />
            <Feature Id="4" Identifier="FID2" Status="Passed" />
            <Feature Id="5" Identifier="FID3" Status="Passed" />
            <Component Id="6" Name="D1" PartNumber="PAD" Package="PAD" Barcode="" IncludedInCurrentVariant="false" ComponentStatus="Passed" TotalFeatures="1">
                <ComponentResult>
                    <Attributes>
                        <FailedFeatures Value="0" />
                    </Attributes>
                </ComponentResult>
                <Feature Id="21606" Identifier="Body1" FeatureStatus="Passed" FeatureInspectionInfo="" MeasurementValid="">
                    <FeatureResult>
                        <Inspection Identifier="FeatureLocator" Type="AI2" status="Passed">
                            <Measurements>
                                <ConfidenceLevel Value="95.292820242958172" Minimum="1" Maximum="100" Target="35" />
                                <Polarity IsFailed="false" />
                            </Measurements>
                        </Inspection>
                        <Inspection Identifier="X-POSITION" Type="GeometryMeasurement" status="Passed">
                            <Measurements>
                                <ParallelLine Distance="0.24886200808679954" MinDistance="0.23" MaxDistance="0.27" Angle="0.14772531447994211" MaxAngle="90" />
                            </Measurements>
                        </Inspection>
                        <Inspection Identifier="Pad-Gap" Type="GeometryMeasurement" status="Passed">
                            <Measurements>
                                <ParallelLine Distance="0.058603726806744492" MinDistance="0.048" MaxDistance="0.08" Angle="0.70909905503968329" MaxAngle="90" />
                            </Measurements>
                        </Inspection>
                        <Inspection Identifier="SR-Opening" Type="GeometryMeasurement" status="Passed">
                            <Measurements>
                                <Deviation Value="0.0340010927630135" Threshold="0.5" Type="RMS" />
                                <Diameter Value="0.55804347481393268" Min="0.4" Max="0.7" />
                            </Measurements>
                        </Inspection>
                        <Inspection Identifier="Appearance" Type="AI2" status="Passed">
                            <Measurements>
                                <ConfidenceLevel Value="94.1349731217522" Minimum="1" Maximum="100" Target="50" />
                                <Polarity IsFailed="false" />
                            </Measurements>
                        </Inspection>
                    </FeatureResult>
                </Feature>
            </Component>
            <BoardPostMeasurementResult Result="Passed" />
        </Board>
        <PanelPostMeasurementResult Result="Passed" />
    </Panel>
</cyber:AOI_INFO>
```

I have an almost what I want XSLT that looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[parent::*]">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:for-each select="attribute::*">
            <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><cyber:AOI_INFO 
xmlns:cyber="http://www.cyberoptics.com/AOI/measure" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.cyberoptics.com/AOI/measure 
c:/xml/Measure.xsd">
    <UserName/>Machine1\User
    <SystemId/>MACHINE1
    <AOIVersion/>4.2.1.24
    <InspectionType/>Inspection
    <PositionUnit/>Millimeter
    <RotationUnit/>Degree
    <XYOffsetReference/>FeatureOrientation
    <CoplanarityUnit/>Angle
    <Panel><Id>4</Id><Name>Panel</Name><PanelStatus>Failed</PanelStatus> 
       <StartTime>07/09/2018 11:25:53</StartTime><EndTime>07/09/2018 
    11:27:40</EndTime><CycleTime>46</CycleTime><TotalFeatures>10804</TotalFeatures> 
   <TotalComponents>10804</TotalComponents><LotCode>New Lot</LotCode><LotSize>0</LotSize><Barcode>Failed to Read Barcode</Barcode><Code>Failed to Read Barcode</Code><NG_Stacker_SlotNumber/></Panel>

        <RecipeName/>11047-01_OP10_WFR4_R2
        <RecipeLastUpdateTime/>
        <CAD/>D:\Panel.XML
        <PanelResult/>
            <Attributes/>
                <FailedBoards><Value>1</Value></FailedBoards>
                <FailedComponents><Value>16</Value></FailedComponents>
                <FailedFeatures><Value>16</Value></FailedFeatures>


        <Feature><Id>32424</Id><Identifier>BC1</Identifier><Status>Failed</Status><Value>Failed to Read Barcode</Value></Feature>
        <Board><Id>1</Id><Name>Board1</Name><BoardStatus>Failed</BoardStatus><TotalFeatures>10804</TotalFeatures><TotalComponents>10804</TotalComponents><Barcode/><Skip>false</Skip></Board>
            <BoardResult/>
                <Attributes/>
                    <FailedComponents><Value>16</Value></FailedComponents>
                    <FailedFeatures><Value>16</Value></FailedFeatures>


            <Feature><Id>2</Id><Identifier>FID0</Identifier><Status>Passed</Status></Feature>
            <Feature><Id>3</Id><Identifier>FID1</Identifier><Status>Passed</Status></Feature>
            <Feature><Id>4</Id><Identifier>FID2</Identifier><Status>Passed</Status></Feature>
            <Feature><Id>5</Id><Identifier>FID3</Identifier><Status>Passed</Status></Feature>
            <Component><Id>6</Id><Name>D1</Name><PartNumber>PAD</PartNumber><Package>PAD</Package><Barcode/><IncludedInCurrentVariant>false</IncludedInCurrentVariant><ComponentStatus>Passed</ComponentStatus><TotalFeatures>1</TotalFeatures></Component>
                <ComponentResult/>
                    <Attributes/>
                        <FailedFeatures><Value>0</Value></FailedFeatures>


                <Feature><Id>21606</Id><Identifier>Body1</Identifier><FeatureStatus>Passed</FeatureStatus><FeatureInspectionInfo/><MeasurementValid/></Feature>
                    <FeatureResult/>
                        <Inspection><Identifier>FeatureLocator</Identifier><Type>AI2</Type><status>Passed</status></Inspection>
                            <Measurements/>
                                <ConfidenceLevel><Value>95.292820242958172</Value><Minimum>1</Minimum><Maximum>100</Maximum><Target>35</Target></ConfidenceLevel>
                                <Polarity><IsFailed>false</IsFailed></Polarity>


                        <Inspection><Identifier>X-POSITION</Identifier><Type>GeometryMeasurement</Type><status>Passed</status></Inspection>
                            <Measurements/>
                                <ParallelLine><Distance>0.24886200808679954</Distance><MinDistance>0.23</MinDistance><MaxDistance>0.27</MaxDistance><Angle>0.14772531447994211</Angle><MaxAngle>90</MaxAngle></ParallelLine>


                        <Inspection><Identifier>Pad-Gap</Identifier><Type>GeometryMeasurement</Type><status>Passed</status></Inspection>
                            <Measurements/>
                                <ParallelLine><Distance>0.058603726806744492</Distance><MinDistance>0.048</MinDistance><MaxDistance>0.08</MaxDistance><Angle>0.70909905503968329</Angle><MaxAngle>90</MaxAngle></ParallelLine>


                        <Inspection><Identifier>SR-Opening</Identifier><Type>GeometryMeasurement</Type><status>Passed</status></Inspection>
                            <Measurements/>
                                <Deviation><Value>0.0340010927630135</Value><Threshold>0.5</Threshold><Type>RMS</Type></Deviation>
                                <Diameter><Value>0.55804347481393268</Value><Min>0.4</Min><Max>0.7</Max></Diameter>


                        <Inspection><Identifier>Appearance</Identifier><Type>AI2</Type><status>Passed</status></Inspection>
                            <Measurements/>
                                <ConfidenceLevel><Value>94.1349731217522</Value><Minimum>1</Minimum><Maximum>100</Maximum><Target>50</Target></ConfidenceLevel>
                                <Polarity><IsFailed>false</IsFailed></Polarity>





            <BoardPostMeasurementResult><Result>Passed</Result></BoardPostMeasurementResult>

        <PanelPostMeasurementResult><Result>Passed</Result></PanelPostMeasurementResult>

</cyber:AOI_INFO>
```

Note that some of the parent elements, such as PanelResult and BoardResult, do not have tags surrounding their child elements and flattened attributes.

I'm pretty sure it is something really simple to get those to surround their child attributes like they should. However, I played around with it long enough that I'm running out of ideas.

Hopefully, someone will recognize my error in the XSLT and be able to point me in the right direction.

Thanks!
Jerry

---

Sorry, I thought some extra details would help. This is what I am getting:

```
<CAD/>D:\Panel.XML
    <PanelResult/>
        <Attributes/>
            <FailedBoards><Value>1</Value></FailedBoards>
            <FailedComponents><Value>16</Value></FailedComponents>
            <FailedFeatures><Value>16</Value></FailedFeatures>
```

And this is what I am looking for:

```
    <CAD>D:\Panel.XML</CAD>
    <PanelResult>
        <Attributes>
            <FailedBoards><Value>1</Value></FailedBoards>
            <FailedComponents><Value>16</Value></FailedComponents>
            <FailedFeatures><Value>16</Value></FailedFeatures>
        </Attributes>
    </PanelResult>
```

Comment: That you are removing namespaces here is a huge red flag. Why are you doing this?

Comment: It is not clear which result you want and you might consider to show us a reduced sample to demonstrate the problem. If you move the `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />` inside the `xsl:element` you get the content inside of the element, it is not clear however  when you want that and when you want to "flatten".

Comment: Sorry, I thought more detail would be better. Please see the updates.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that by "flattening out" you mean you want to convert all attributes to elements?

Comment: That is correct. I think I may have the terminology wrong but that is essentially it.  What I want is for each element to contain any elements and values along with the attributes set out as elements as well.

Comment: As for the namespaces, I really am not concerned with them here. The files come from a manufacturing machine that creates them, not from some possibly questionable outside source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you simply want to replace attributes with elements bearing the same name, only nested under an `Attributes` element beneath their original parent.

This should do the trick:  See [XSLT Fiddle Example](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMv).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element()[./@*[namespace-uri() != 'http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance' and namespace-uri() != 'xmlns' ]]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <Attributes>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./@*" />    
            </Attributes>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="@*[namespace-uri() != 'http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance' and namespace-uri() != 'xmlns' ]">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Explanation:

### Template 1

*i.e. (`match="@*|node()"`)*

Match everything and copy the contents as is, applying templates to that content as necessary.

### Template 2

*i.e. (`match="element()[./@*[namespace-uri() != 'http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance' and namespace-uri() != 'xmlns' ]]"`)*

- Match any element which contains at least one attribute*.
- By matching on the element it ensures that we only create the `Attributes` tag once for this element, rather than once per attribute.
- - NB: In the match condition I filtered out anything with the namespace uri `xmlns` to avoid removing namespace definitions, and filtered `xsi`'s URI to avoid removing standard XML definitions; since these have a purpose as attributes but are likely not wanted by you in your elements.

### Template 3

i.e. *(`@*[namespace-uri() != 'http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance' and namespace-uri() != 'xmlns']`)*

This matches the attributes themselves, and converts them into elements.

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: I noticed that the hierarchy isn't completely preserved. It looks like I made each element stand on its own. For instance, the board element actually encapsulates the components, features and various measurements.

Comment: @JerryK are you saying that the above doesn't fully solve your problem?  If not, please can you provide more info on the issue (ideally with examples), as most likely I've misunderstood the issue...  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like I did something wrong when copying your example. It actually looks perfect when I get it all copied properly. Thanks again.